# How to do binding for a global ApplicationBar in Windows Phone with MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvmcross

I am trying to create an ApplicationBar which will be global to my Windows Phone application. That is, I want to create and set up binding for the ApplicationBar once, but have it displayed on multiple different pages (views).

For now my approach has been to create the ApplicationBar in the App.xaml file, so that I can use it as a static resource from my views. My App.xaml file currently looks like this:

```
<Application 
    x:Class="MyApplication.WindowsPhone.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:valueConverters="clr-namespace:MyApplication.WindowsPhone.ValueConverters"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Core.ViewModels;assembly=MyApplication.Core">

    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="GlobalAppBar" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Minimized">
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Action 1" Click="MenuItem1_Click"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Action 2" Click="MenuItem2_Click"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
        <valueConverters:NativeVisibilityConverter x:Name="VisibilityConverter" />
        <viewModels:MenuViewModel x:Key="MenuViewModel" />
    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService 
            Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" 
            Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

</Application>
```

That works fine, and I can reuse the ApplicationBar across my views, for instance:

```
<views:BaseView
    x:Class="MyApplication.WindowsPhone.Views.FirstView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApplication.WindowsPhone.Views"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    ApplicationBar="{StaticResource GlobalAppBar}">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageTitle}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</views:BaseView>
```

However, now I would like to bind the Text and Click properties of each ApplicationBarMenuItem to properties and commands in my MenuViewModel, but I'm not sure how I can go about doing that. Is it possible to achieve binding to a ViewModel from the App.xaml file, or is there some other path I need to take?

Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone AppBar's are naive rather than Silverlight controls - so they are not bindable direclty.

However, several wrappers exist for them - search for "windowsphone bindable application bar" and you'll find several wrappers - e.g. http://cimbalino.org includes one via a `Behavior` or http://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com is a wrapper just for this problem.

When you use a wrapper, then you should be easily able to set its `DataContext` to your `MenuViewModel`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond!

So as far as I can tell it is not straight forward to achieve what I was after, which is a global application bar. As far as I can see, if I go for a wrapper, I will not be able to set up the application bar once and reuse it across different pages e.g. by setting the ApplicationBar property of each page.

Comment: I think you can - but I could be wrong. I don't think this is MvvmCross related - I think it's a general WinPhone question - hopefully some WP expert will be able to assist